# How to force create a Google Inbox Trips bundle?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Google Inbox has a [Trips feature](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6228360?hl=en) that bundles reservations. You can add an arbitrary email to an existing one of these Trip bundles. Inbox automatically creates new bundles when it detects reservation emails.

[image: Move to Trips leads to a submenu that requires choosing a specific trip]

My wife and I are planning a new trip, but we're in the early stages, so we haven't actually reserved anything yet, so there's no bundle for our trip. Inbox won't let me add an email to Trips without picking a bundle. How can we manually create a new Trip bundle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just discovered a way to do this - You can force add a trip bundle in Google Inbox using the Google Trips app ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.travel.onthego) / [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-trips/id1081561570?mt=8)). Just search a destination, then create a trip and it will show up in your Google Inbox a few minutes later.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me either

Comment: How many minutes is „a few minutes later”? No trip showing up after 5.

Comment: Maybe it only works for Android...The trip showed up for me after about 5 minutes.

Comment: Tried on Android today, didn't work either.

Comment: Worked for me on iOS.

Comment: The author of the article in FiXXXeR's answer now recommends this method. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUe8xNgPT3E

Answer (score 6):

Using a Google Apps Script makes it possible to create a "fake" trip email to kick one off, but it's been hit-and-miss for me this way:
http://www.scottgreenstone.com/2016/03/manuallycreatetrips.html

There is also quite a long delay until the trip is created after receiving the email, so it is hard to tell whether it has worked or not while you are trying to get the script details correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's code to do it here:  https://github.com/richardtguy/trip-maker including a running web app to do it for you: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx7XyklxcWdxh9QJk3aS7k5LukoMoTxC3DRvJZMGq3PCnvVSluP/exec